# Loading models in LibGDX from obj omitts texture coordinates

Tags: libgdx, 3dsmax, wavefront

I'm using 3ds max to draw my models and attach textures to them, when I'm done I export the model to `.obj` file format and then load it in libgdx `new AssetManager().load("path", Model.class)`
However, I think libgdx messes it up, or maybe something wrong with the export tools. I'm hoping to receive an insight on this problem.

Comment: Use fbx converter to generate g3db. They work better then .obj files

Comment: the problem is that fbx converter gives an unexpected error